# Filtering string output/extracting one key value pair

Tags: java, filter, output, extract

This:

```
txtTaxRate.setText(GetURLContent.getData(sURL));
```

Outputs this:

```
{"taxrate":0.15,"year":2017,"developer":"","salary":10000.0,"status":"S"}
```

How do I output ONLY the taxrate (0.15)? This is a json to string, or key value pairs. My professor said this can be done by "getting" something from this output, in one line, and he says I'm close but I really don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know for sure that your string will always have the format you showed, this line will do the trick:

```
txtTaxRate.setText(GetURLContent.getData(sURL).substring(11, 15));
```

If you don't want to use magic numbers, you can use a combination of `indexOf and`substring` to achieve this, for example like this:

```
String data = GetURLContent.getData(sURL);
int fromIndex = data.indexOf("\"taxrate\":") + "\"taxrate\":".length();
int toIndex = data.indexOf(",\"year\"");
txtTaxRate.setText(data.substring(fromIndex, toIndex));
```

Obviously, this is not very pretty. You could use a [JSON parser](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) for a more general solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods you can use: `inStr()` and `substring()`. 
You can find them here: [String class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Use this code:

```
String str = "{\"taxrate\":0.15,\"year\":2017,\"developer\":\"\",\"salary\":10000.0,\"status\":\"S\"}";
String taxrate = str
        .substring(0, str.indexOf(","))
        .substring(str.indexOf(":") + 1);
System.out.println(taxrate);
```

will print:

```
0.15
```

First you get the string up to the first occurrence of `","`.  
Then in that substring you get the part after `":"`.

Answer (score 0):

The `GetURLContent.getData(sURL)` returns a string which `txtTaxRate.setText()` is using. Now since you are getting a string so either you can convert it to `JSON` first or the other simple way is as shown below:

```
String s = GetURLContent.getData(sURL);
String[] arr = s.substring(1,s.length()-1).split(",");
String requiredText = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(s2 -> s2.contains("taxrate")).findFirst().get();
```

Now when you do `System.out.println(requiredText );` you will see the output `"taxrate":0.15`.
Also pls note that you require `java 8` for above solution to work.